# UISearchBar textDidChange Delays for Remote calls

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I am trying to determine how to get `UISearchBar` to delay calling `textDidChange` till a few millisecs have passed.  My goal is to aggregate multiple keyboard entries into one remote web service call.. As I have it now I call the server every keystroke and this is way too much.

If there is not some way within one of the `UISearchBar` Delegate methods... is there some other way to accomplish the same goal... namely just do not call the server until the user has paused entering keys?

I have been using this delegate method:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use an NSTimer.

Do this:

1. Create an NSTimer that calls your remote web service call and run it when the user starts typing.
2. Each time the user enters a key have the timer reset and start again.
3. If the user stopped typing the NSTimer will fire your web service call.